# iOS - 3G slow connection issue when connecting to back-end API server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, connection, nsurlconnection, 3g

Currently I am working on an App which requires several calls to a back-end server.
When on WiFi the App connects fine and downloads very fast the data, but when on 3G the connection seems a bit unstable and very slow.

So I have done some very simple test case (which you find below). And it seems that NSURLConnection is not getting data at the same response speed.

(Do note that I have removed the URL of the real server I connected to)

Test cases:

Placed on a server the following php script:

```
<?php echo 'hello world' ?>
```

Grabbed an iPhone, put WiFi off and made sure it had a proper 3G connection.

Used the following Objective-C code to connect to the server:

> NSURL  * url           = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someserver.com/test.php"];
>
> NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
>
> NSDate * startDate     = [NSDate date];
>
> NSLog(@"START");
>
> NSURLConnection * connection = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
>
> NSLog(@"%3.2f", -[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);

This returns on 3G - 1.47 seconds. So this might be normal if you connect for the first time using 3G, since it needs to initialise. But now comes the interesting part. If you repeat this call several times it returns the following:

1.47 seconds

2.33 seconds

1.1  seconds

I have tested this using two different iPhones and two different providers:T-Mobile and KPN. I also tried this using the async version of NSURLConnection, which I normally use, but this also returns the same results.

(Other things I also did: checked Apple's Reachabilty.h, removed the DNS look-up by replacing the server url by the ip-number, used an other server and used https://www.google.nl/search?q=%i, arc4random(), also tried [NSString alloc]initWithContentOfURL]. All returned a similar result, except when using the iPhone browser: Safari, which responded immediately.)

I have also tested something similar using an Android phone, but then I get a fast response 500ms (using the same providers).

Did someone encountered this before? If so, how did you solve this issue and what causes this problem with the connection?

Comment: @H2CO3 I already done that: "I also tried this using the async version of NSURLConnection, which I normally use, but this also returns the same results."

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue in that naturally over a 3g connection the post request would be slightly slower depending on the amount of data sent. However if I send over a synchronous request its quicker for me than the async method. What I have noticed is that over a 3g connection using async the OS has to close the connections and you may notice in the log "purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn" seems to add some time to method execution.